# Prove that $D =\{x \in \mathbb{N} | \Phi_x(x)\uparrow\}$ is **not** recursively enumerable

Tags: computability, proof-techniques

So I tried to prove that $D =\{x \in \mathbb{N} | \Phi_x(x)\uparrow\}$ is **not** recursively enumerable in the following way:

- let's suppose that $g$ is the computable function that represents $D$ $$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1 & \mbox{if} & \Phi_x(x)\downarrow\ \\ 0 & \mbox{if} & \Phi_x(x)\uparrow\ \end{array}\right.$$
- let's suppose that it exists a Turing machine of index $i_0$ such that $g = \Phi_{i_0}$, than it is possible to define the function: $$g'(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \uparrow & \mbox{if} & g(x)=1=\Phi_{i_0}(x) \\ 0 & \mbox{if} & g(x)=0=\Phi_{i_0}(x) \end{array}\right.$$
- so $g'$ is also computable thus there is a Turing machine of index $i_1$ such that $g' = \Phi_{i_1}$, but then we will have that:
  $$\Phi_{i_1}(i_1)\downarrow \iff g'(i_1) = 0 \iff g(i_1) = 0 \iff \Phi_{i_1}(i_1)\uparrow $$
  $$\Phi_{i_1}(i_1)\uparrow \iff g'(i_1) \uparrow \iff g(i_1) = 1 \iff \Phi_{i_1}(i_1)\downarrow $$

which is a contraddiction. So an index $i_1$ doesn't exists that is the index $i_0$ that computes $g$ doesn't exists, that is $g$ is not recursive so $D$ is **not** recursive enumerable.

I'm quite confused on this topic, so tell me if I made any kind of error.

Comment: I think there is a slight error in your definition of $D$. Do you mean $D = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} | \Phi_i (x) \uparrow \}$ ? Note that $\Phi_i$ denotes one goedelized Turing Machine with  Goedelnumber $i$

Comment: Yes you are rigth. Thank you... anything else? I think I also messed up the last definition. I wrote that if $g$ is not recursive than $D$ is not recursive enumerable, but I don't find any theorem that states that.

Comment: You proved that D is not **recursive** (also known as decidable) because you starting assumption was that there is a computable $g$ which decides membeship of $D$. To prove that $D$ is not recursively enumerable, your starting assumption must be tht there is a computable $h$ whose image is $D$.

Comment: I'm doing a mess here, but I came with this: $\psi_d(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1 & \mbox{if} & x \in D \\ \uparrow & \mbox{if} & x \notin D\end{array}\right.$ this means that $D=dom(\psi_d)$. So $x\in A \iff \exists y  \text{ such that }  \Phi_y(x)\uparrow$. Then   $\psi_d(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 1 & \mbox{if} &\exists y.  \Phi_y(x)\uparrow\\ \uparrow & \mbox{if} & \exists y.  \Phi_y(x)\downarrow\end{array}\right.$ but that is a contraddiction.

Comment: so $D$ isn't recursive enumerable. Am I right?

Comment: I think $D$ is r.e. Sketch: You can define a function $h$ which can enumerate all elements of $D$. $h$ would somehow start checking if $h(0)$ existis in $D$. That means, it would check, if there exists one $\Phi_i$ where $\Phi_i(0)\uparrow$. If so, $0$ is enumerated in $D$ and $h$ tries the same with $x=1$ and so on... Please correct me, if my idea has false assumptions.

Comment: Yes but checking if $\Phi_i(0)\uparrow$ it's not computable, isn't it? I understood that there is no way to know if a function terminates or not its computation. I'm really confused on this topic so please have patience with me.

Comment: If $h$ is computable, is the important point, you got that right. However I think that $h$ is computable (or at least we can modify $h$ to be computable). Lets modify your set $D$ a bit. Define $D_s :=\{ x \in \mathbb{N} | \Phi_i(x) [s]\}$. Then $D = \bigcup_{s \in \mathbb{N}} D_{s}$. Clearly, we can construct a computable function $h_s$ for each $D_s$ and the union of r.e. sets is always r.e. Do you understand my argument?

Comment: I understand that the intention is to create smaller sets from $D$ that have computable functions, but I don't understand how you do that. What is $\Phi_i(x)[s]$?

Comment: @Panzerkroete $D$ (as defined in the question, currently) is *definitely* not r.e.: if it were, the halting problem would be recursive (being both r.e. and co-r.e.).

Comment: @Panzerkroete First of all, there's a typo in your definition of $D_s$: I believe you mean $D_s=\{x:\Phi_i(x)[s]\uparrow\}$. Second, note that $\{x: \Phi_i(x)\uparrow\}$ is the *intersection*, not the *union*, of the $D_s$s. (Also, there seems to be some issue over what $D$ is: in the OP, $D$ is the set of indices of machines which don't halt on their own input, so there is no "$i$" playing  a role, but what's discussed in the comments seems to be the set of indices for machines which fail to halt on *some* input. That's still not r.e., though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrej states, what you've (correctly) done is show that $D=\{x:\Phi_x(x)\uparrow\}$ is not *recursive*. However, there are plenty of sets which are recursively enumerable but not recursive, so you're not done yet: you need to show that $D$ is not the domain of any partial recursive function.

*REMARK: Some texts define a set to be r.e. if it is the **range** of a **total** recursive function, or is empty. This is slightly less elegant since it requires a separate clause to handle $\emptyset$; it also generalizes less well if one looks into higher computability theory. However, regardless of what definition your book gives, the equivalence between them should be a very early exercise.*

There are a couple ways to do this:

- You could argue directly: suppose $D$ is the domain of $\Phi_i$. Can you use the recursion theorem to cook up a $j$ such that $\Phi_j(j)\downarrow\iff \Phi_i(j)\downarrow$? Do you see why this gives a contradiction?
- Alternately, note that $D$ is the complement of the *Halting Problem* $H=\{x: \Phi_x(x)\downarrow\}$. Two early results in computability theory are that (i) $H$ is r.e. but not recursive and (ii) if a set and its complement are r.e., then they are each recursive. Do you see how to prove each of these facts, and apply them to the current problem? *(Note that this approach isn't actually much different than the first one, since the recursion theorem is used in proving (i).)*

*REMARK: Some texts define the Halting Problem differently, some common alternate candidates being $\{x: \Phi_x(0)\downarrow\}$ and $\{\langle x, y\rangle:\Phi_x(y)\downarrow\}$. It's a good exercise to show that these are all r.e. and Turing equivalent (indeed $1$-equivalent!) to each other.*

By similar arguments you can show that minor variations of $D$ are also not r.e. - e.g. can you show that $\{x: \Phi_x(17)\uparrow\}$ is not r.e.?

---

Responding to the comments: one may be tempted to try to enumerate $D$, or things like $D$, by looking at *approximations given by stages*. E.g. we could let $D_s=\{x:\Phi_x(x)[s]\uparrow\}$; this is the set of indices of machines which on their own input don't halt *in fewer than $s$ steps*. The $D_s$s are r.e. - indeed, uniformly recursive - and approximate $D$ "from above" in the sense that $D=\bigcap_{s\in\mathbb{N}} D_s$. However, this ultimately isn't relevant to this problem since the intersection of infinitely many r.e. sets need not be r.e.